# Magnetic Ethernet connector

Tags: ethernet

I came across some schematics for connecting the magnetic jack to the processor, I found, some connected TCT only to Vdd through Ferrite Bead, resistor, or direct.
Also, I found some connected both TCT and RCT through a Ferrite bead or resistor to Vdd.
Which one is the good way?
Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details on your project: Global description ? what do you call magnetic jack ? Processor type ? What should be connected to it ? As you said there is a lot of different way to power a circuit (I think it´s what you want to do) and each solution is good for one type of utilisation

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the PHY you've got (assuming your 'processor' is a SoC with integrated PHY and the 'magnetic jack' is a TP jack with integrated magnetics).

Check the datasheet and post back the details if you can't make it out.